# Set type dynamically for method call

Tags: c#, generics

I have a static function:

```
    public static MyCollection<T> Parse<T>(string? json) where T : BaseClass
    {
       ...
    }
```

And it works fine. It makes decisions internally based on the type and produces the correct collection.

But, the collection I want is based on a file name coming in from another source and I was hoping to have one collection and dynamically set the type, as in:

```
   Type t;
   if (name == "Certain name") t = typeof(CertainChildClassOfBaseClass);
   if (name == "Other name") t = typeof(OtherChildClassOfBaseClass);

   var myCollection = ParsingService.Parse<t>(jsonString);
```

This obviously doesn't work, but is what I'm trying possible? I don't really want to write a bunch of if/else blocks with nearly identical content just so each one can have a different type (I already wrote those type-specific blocks inside the `Parse` function - doing the same branching twice seems like maybe I've made a more fundamental mistake). I am open to suggestions on how to do this the "right" way. Maybe I have to do this with reflection, which doesn't thrill me, but isn't the end of the world. One possible issue is the my parsing service is static.

Help is always appreciated.

Comment: You could create a second overload for the `Parse` method that takes a regular parameter of type `Type` instead of an actual type parameter, or use reflection to create the generic method definition and invoke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, I would recommend making `Parse` non generic, and then have a generic overload:

```
public static MyCollection<BaseClass> Parse(Type type, string? json)
{
   ...
}

public static MyCollection<T> Parse<T>(string? json) where T : BaseClass
{
   return (MyCollection<T>)Parse(typeof(T), json);
}
```

But you can't make `MyCollection` contravariant because it's a concrete class, so that cast is illegal. And anyway, contravariant containers are dangerous to use (just look at arrays, for example).

The other method is to use reflection to get the version of the method you want (a process known as "closing" the generic type):

```
var genericMethod = typeof(/* class containing Parse */).GetMethod("Parse");
var method = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type); // type will be substituted for your 'T', above
object collection = method.Invoke(json); // call the method
```

And here we hit another snag: `collection`'s type will be `object`, and you need to cast it to something else. But you can't use `MyCollection<T>` because you don't know `T`, and you can't use `MyCollection<BaseClass>` because, well, no contravariance, again.

So really the main blocker is that `MyCollection` type. As long as it is that way, you have no easy way to go around it. You could instead return a non generic collection, like `ICollection` or `IList`, but then you lose type safety and you'll have to keep casting more later. It's up to you, really.

Comment: Ok. I'll just write the if/else block. :) Thanks for the assist.